# Smooth signal with Hanning

Tags: signal-analysis, window-functions, smoothing

I have an acceleration record and i want to smooth it's spectrum by using a hanning window with Bandwidth=0.5 Hz.

How could i do that?

Example in python/matlab will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth it's spectrum"?

Comment: Take the FFT of my data and after that to smooth the spectrum using a hanning window.

Comment: I think you apply the Hann window (*"Hanning"* is an old misnomer conflating *"Hann"* with *"Hamming"*, no one with the name "Hanning") to the time-domain data for it to smooth the frequency-domain data.

Comment: I have recently encountered the same problem and my data type is also acceleration. Can you please tell me if you have solved this problem now in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Hann window of size $N$ and use it to window your signal $x$ using the MATLAB command

```
w=hann(N);
x_windowed = x.*w;
```

Since you specified BW of 0.5Hz, you need normalize it with your sampling rate $F_s$. That is $w_s = \pi 0.5/F_s$. You need to choose $N$ such that your main lobe width of the Hann window falls at $w_s$. It is not an easy problem and you may have to do trial and error initially. You can use `freqz(w)` command in MATLAB to see the frequency plot of Hann window. You can hover an see at what normalized frequency your main lobe width is.

[image]

Comment: My signal has different size compared to the Hann window. So how can i do the multiplication without causing error?

Comment: If your signal size is $N$, generate hann window with size $N$. Just change the argument of hann command.